# Get stored procedure result from row number

Tags: php, sql-server, stored-procedures

I call a stored procedure from php like so:

```
$query = "exec [dbo].[SRC_GET_CLIENT_DIARY] @login = 'user01'";
```

Then I fetch the result via `sqlsrv_fetch_array`.

Knowing that I can't edit the stored procedure and the 3 first rows of the result are reserved for the system admin. Is there a way (beside of a simple *for* loop) to make the result start at row number 4?

Comment: For an SP, the output result set is controlled completely by the SQL in the SP. If the resultset from the SP isn't as desired, then it's the SP that needs to be changed. Considering that you're saying you can't change it, perhaps you should be using, or designing, a different one.

Comment: Ok, so I guess I have no choices other than using an ugly loop ^^ thanks for the answer